# How to send data in the form of a single or multiple objects via @Input in angular?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular12

I have a couple of objects that I want to send to a child component but am unable to as it is undefined in the child component.

Here's the code --

```
PARENT COMPONENT
searchObj!: Search;
resultObj:any;

this.resultLabelObj = {
      CSSRKPILabel:this.CSSRKPILabel,
      CountryLabel:this.CountryLabel,
      DealerOutletCodeLabel:this.DealerOutletCodeLabel,
      SwitchToLabel:this.SwitchToLabel,
      InstantFeedbackLabel:this.InstantFeedbackLabel,
      SurveyFeedbackLabel:this.SurveyFeedbackLabel,
      ServiceRemindersLabel:this.ServiceRemindersLabel,
      SurveyAnalysisLabel:this.SurveyAnalysisLabel,
      PostServiceFollowupLabel:this.PostServiceFollowupLabel,
      PostSalesFollowupLabel :this.PostSalesFollowupLabel,
      ToDateLabel :this.ToDateLabel,
      VehicleLabel:this.VehicleLabel,
      SearchLabel:this.SearchLabel,
      TargetVsAchievementLabel :this.TargetVsAchievementLabel,
    };

PARENT HTML
<child [counters]="{labelObj:resultObj,searchObj:searchObj}></child>

CHILD COMPONENT
@Input()
counters:any;
label = this.counters.labelObj;
search:Search = this.counters.searchObj;
```

Even when I'm sending a single object, it is still showing undefined in the child component.

```
PARENT COMPONENT
searchObj!: Search;


PARENT HTML
<child [counters]="searchObj"></child>

CHILD COMPONENT
@Input()
counters!:Search;

searchObj:Search = this.counters;
```

I want to access the values of resultLabelObj in the child template. I'm able to print it directly in the child's template but if I try to log it inside ngOnInit() or use its value somewhere inside the child's template, its showing undefined.
TIA.

Comment: you tried to log it to console inside `ngOnInit()` of child component ? what do you get?

Comment: yes I did. Its showing undefined  inside ngOnInit(). But If I print it directly in the child template, I'm getting the value. But that's not what I want. I want to access the values of the object in child component template which I'm unable to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely send an object to child component and if you need to send several objects you can easily send them as an array of objects. Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-output-angular-mcua1d

Using interface 'Something' as an example of type.

I don't know how you're setting values for searchObj and resultObj, so here's an example of setting one object and one array of objects in parent component onInit:

```
somethingObj: Something;
somethingArr: Something[];


ngOnInit() {
    this.somethingObj = {
      something1: 'value of something1',
      something2: 'value of something2',
    };
    this.somethingArr = [
      {
        something1: 'value of something1',
        something2: 'value of something2',
      },
      {
        something1: 'value of something3',
        something2: 'value of something4',
      },
      {
        something1: 'value of something5',
        something2: 'value of something6',
      },
    ];
}
```

Then pass them to child component in template:

```
<app-child [fromParentObj]="somethingObj" [fromParentArr]="somethingArr"></app-child>
```

Get them in Child component:

```
@Input() fromParentObj: Something;
@Input() fromParentArr: Something[];

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.fromParentObj);
    console.log(this.fromParentArr);
}
```

And just to see them in template, you can add this to child component's html:

```
<code
  >Object From Parent:
  <pre>{{ fromParentObj | json }}</pre>
</code>

<code
  >Array of objects From Parent:
  <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of fromParentArr">
    <pre>{{ obj | json }}</pre>
  </ng-container>
</code>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I'm able to print it like this `{{ fromParentObj | json }}`. but what I need is to print certain values from `fromParentObj` .For eg -- `abcLabel = fromParentObj.abcLabel` and then print `{{abcLabel}}` which I'm unable to do.

Comment: also, while logging inside the `ngOnInit()` of child component, I'm getting undefined.

Comment: Can you share the code you're working on that gives these problems?